# Should I ignore spam I find useful?

Tags: ethics

I received spam in the form of a physical letter. It just happens that it is an ad of a furniture store and I'm looking for a store to buy some furniture.  I don't know any stores at a convenient location other than the one advertised. However choosing that store would validate the spam.

There are 2 things that I find unethical - physical paper was wasted and mass unwanted letters were sent.  One possible course of action is putting the letter for recycling and making a note to not go to this store. What makes me doubt is that I actually received two such letters from two different stores and soon maybe there will be no stores left.

What should I take into account to make a decision how to proceed?  Or, to make the question more general:  **Is it personally unethical to reward (by responding to) a marketing practice that I find unethical?**  Or (to be more general still): **Is it a moral imperative to boycott businesses that I know to have practices that violate my moral standards?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing how to react to advertising is an entirely individual personal choice and not one that **Philosophy SE** has anything to add to.

Comment: @MichaelK I didn't ask what choice should I make, but what factors I should consider in making this choice.

Comment: Unlike email spam, physical letters cost the sender money, so this sort of advertising could be considered more legitimate/honest than email spam. Also, lots of stores advertise by mail, so, as you point out, to be consistent, you'd have to stop visiting many stores. Third, punishing yourself (by not purchasing goods/services you need) to punish others is tricky at best: who are you harming more? Is it worth the harm to you? Finally, you don't have to tell the store that their spam letter got you to come in, so it doesn't validate the spam.

Comment: @martinkunev I think this is a great question, however, as phrased, it is very specific.  I have edited to make it more general in the hopes that it will be less likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends entirely on you.** On the one hand, you would be supporting a business which you do not like for what they are doing. On the other hand, your relationship with the business could be mutually beneficial. They could be the cheapest in the area or more convenient due to being closer to you. It all boils down to how you personally view their actions and overall impact on society.

As a personal example, there is a large company in my country which uses a super-annoying advertising personality. Compared to him, Kim Jong Un is a popular Korean fella. Me, and many other people I know, choose not to buy things from this company because they pollute the world with heinous ads. Many others do not care. And it's fine. That is their choice.

**Edit:** To answer the newly added general questions, I think it depends on your view of the good old [categorical imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative) and whether you think  that the behavior of the company is so undesirable that you need to act on it.

Comment: I made some edits. As you are probably aware you may roll them back or continue editing. I don't know how to answer this question for what it's worth. Welcome to this SE.